# gettin wrong values using sin function in c

Tags: c, math

I would  like to calculate the sin value of an angle here what I've done :

```
#define M_PI    3.14159265358979

void calculate( int angle) {
    unsigned short x = 0, y= 0 , z=0;  I need the 
    angle *=  M_PI/180;
    x =(short) (sin(angle)* 65535);   
    y =(short) (sin(angle+(120* (M_PI/180))) *65535);
    z =(short) (sin(angle - (120* (M_PI/180))) *65535);
    printf("X angle  value =  %d \n", x);
    printf("Y angle value = %d  \n",y);
    printf("Z angle value = %d \n",z);    
}
```

what I get is

```
Z angle value = 7299
X angle  value =  55145
Y angle value = 3091
```

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong and Idea ?

I was expecting : 
x = 65535
y = Z = 65535/2  = 32767 
but it's not the case !
the value of the angle is 90°

**UPDATE**

I've change the code like :
Now angle is float

```
#define M_PI    3.14159265358979

unsigned short x = 0, y= 0, z=0;
angle *= M_PI/180.0;
x = (unsigned short) (sin(angle)* 65536);
y = (unsigned short) (sin(angle+(120* (M_PI/180.))) *65536);
z = (unsigned short) (sin(angle + (240* (M_PI/180.0))) *65536);
```

Now I get the right value for the X but not for Y,Z  those are equal to 0 ?

Comment: What is the value of `angle`?

Comment: Your `angle` is `int`. if you do `angle *=  M_PI/180;` It will be very roughly rounded.

Comment: @undur_gongor   the angle value is 90 ° I forgot to write it I've changed the type of angle to float but it didn't help much !

Comment: Since you are using floating point calculations with `double` type, you should keep _all_ your literals as double too. For example: `y = (unsigned short) (sin(angle+(120.0* (M_PI/180.0))) *65535.0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are multiplying by `65536` but it should be `65535`.

Also, you have not allowed for sines to be negative (the `y` and `z` calculations both yield a negative sine). It should be

```
x =(unsigned short) (32768.0 + sin(angle)* 32767.0);
```

But I don't understand why you are not using signed `short`

```
x =(short) (sin(angle)* 32767);
```

**UPDATE**

In the case that you want 16-bit absolute values as you commented below:

```
x =(unsigned short) (fabs(sin(angle))* 65535);
```

Note the `65535` and not `65536`, which would be out of range for sine of 90°.

Comment: I want to use 16 Bit for the sin abs that's why I use unsigned

Comment: @Engine do `y` and `z` in the same way, replacing `(angle)` with `(angle+(120* (M_PI/180)))` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing `int` with `double`. Your argument `angle` must not be an integer, as it gets multiplied with M_PI/180, which will be rounded to zero. Angle times 0 is zero.

You can keep angle as integer, but when multipling with M_PI/180.0 store the result in a float or double variable. And you have to adjust your printf statement to print floats instead of decimals.

Comment: replace variable by angle

Comment: @user1234567  please check the update of my question

Comment: Probably your values exceed the range of short. Why do you multiply with 65536, which is a uncommon high number. And don't add questions to a question which got answered. Otherwise it is difficult to follow the answers and you can only accept one answer.